# pyspark toPandas() operation on timestamps before the epoch

Tags: pyspark, python-datetime, epoch

I am unable to apply certain methods on spark dataframes that have pre-epoch timestamps

e.g.

```
df = ss.createDataFrame([('1969-12-31 18:59:59',)], ['col_timestamp'])
df.select(to_timestamp(df.col_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).toPandas()
```

gives error ...

```
  File "C:\venv37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 201, in fromInternal
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts // 1000000).replace(microsecond=ts % 1000000)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: i'm not able to replicate the issue on spark 3.1.3 -- it works just fine

Comment: Thanks @samkart.  Unfortunately our system is using spark 2.4.3 and it would not be easy to upgrade at this stage.

Comment: I'm also only getting this error on Windows platform,  does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the new parser:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp

df = spark.createDataFrame([('1969-12-31 18:59:59',)], ['col_timestamp'])
df.select(to_timestamp(df.col_timestamp, 'y-M-d H:m:s')).toPandas()
```

Comment: thanks, but new parser is not working for me either.

Comment: have you tried ```spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")``` before the operation?

Comment: thanks.  Yes,  still gives the error.